# WAMP2 server installation and testing the connection with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, wampserver

I installed WAMP. The issue I am facing with connection between PHP and MySQL. When I go to `WWW` directory and make changes to the file  localhost, dbuser = root and password = blank as follows:``

```
<?php 
    $link = MySQL_connect('localhost','root',''); 
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . MySQL_error()); 
    } 
    echo 'Connection OK'; MySQL_close($link); 
?>
```

Then I tried to test the connection .
It does not say `Connection OK` rather it redirects me to the search engine yahoo.

I also tried to test php scripts but the browser does not respond. and it redirects to the homepage "yahoo answer.com"

Kindly help me. I am at my wits end as why is it not executing the script and the connection with `mysql`.

Comment: first of all, mysql_connect is deprecated, you shall use mysqli_connect. And actually it's running fine in my computer. How did you access your php file from your browser's address bar?

Comment: thanks Yohanes for the kind reply. do u mean  to say that mysql doesnt link with PHP in WAMP? I accesssed my php file  from folder "myproject" which I created in www directory. but it did not execute dspite WAMP being green all the time.  is it something to do with Port 80 allocation ....port 80 is allocated apache server. is it rght or do i need to change . Kindky advise

Comment: from your internet browser, have you tried something like `http://localhost/YOUR_FILENAME.php` ? as long as no other application used port 80, you should be just fine, I also use port 80.

Comment: Thanks a lot yohanes ..I got it solved by changing sql_comment to sqli_comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are being sent to a search engine then you are either not entering the url correctly or you dont have the HOST file setup correctly.

The url for that test script should be

```
http://localhost/testmysql.php
```

However the most likely issue is that you dont have the HOST file correctly configured to know where to find the domain name of `localhost`

To check that, edit `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` it shoudl look like this

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
::1   localhost
```

**HOW TO EDIT THE HOSTS FILE**

The hosts file is protected by windows, in order to save it you must have Administrator privilages.
Vista/W7/W8 you may think you are an Administrator BUT YOU ARE NOT.

To successfully save the hosts file do this to launch your editor with Admin Privilages.

Locate your editors icon on the desktop or from the Start menus ( notepad will do if you have nothing else )
right click + shift  over your chosen editor icon - will show a menu.
select "Run As Administrator" from the menu.
Navigate your editor to the c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file.

When you have made changes you will now be allowed to save them.

Comment: Thanks Riggs ..ur reply really helped a lot